# Min of Grouping with Max

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question regarding how to write a query of the following table:

```
File#        Test#        Phase#      
----------  ----------  ----------
A           1           1         
A           1           2         
A           2           1
```

which result should be as the following :

```
  File#        Test#        Phase#      
----------  ----------  ----------
  A             2           1
```

What I would like to do is to have the **test** with the **lowest phases*!!

Further explanations:

Test 1 has two phases( Phase 1, Phase 2)

Test 2 has only one phase ( Phase)

Thus , for file A , the test with lowest number of phases is **test 2**

My trails:

I was able to take the max value of phases for each test by the following query:

```
Select File, Test , Max(Phase) as MaxPhases
From table
Group by File, Test
```

Then , I thought of taking the minimum values of the result, which It should be like this :

```
Select Min (t1.MaxPhases ) 
From ( Select File, Test , Max(Phase) as MaxPhases
    From table
    Group by File, Test) t1
```

but I could not add the other info of File#, Test#... I was able to take the minimum only..

Comment: why not `A 1 1` in your result?

Comment: You mean "Max Test# and Min Phase#" ?

Comment: if you mean get the row which has the min(Phase#) see: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-to-get-the-max-row. Otherwise please expand your question.

Comment: stackoverflow is not intended to have people write the code for you. Show us what you tried and try to be more clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @vkp Please read my explanation

Comment: Ah, you are not talking of the lowest *phase*, but the lowest *record count*. And if test #2 had three records and test #1 only two, your result would  show the two records of test #1 instead, yes?

Comment: And what about the file number: Do you need a query that pics the records for one file number only or for several?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner for one file number only ..

Comment: This answers my second question. The other question: It is the test with the lowest number of records you want to show. So if that test has several records, the result contains all these records. Is this correct?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner  yes, exactly ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100586/discussion-between-programming-lover-and-thorsten-kettner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the analytic function COUNT OVER. So you get the phase count per test along with the original records. Then pick the records of the top tests (all tests with the minimum count). Then order by test and phase to show the records in desired order.

```
select
  test, phase
from
(
  select top(1) with ties 
    test, phase
  from
  (
    select test, phase, count(*) over (partition by test) as cnt
    from table
    where file = 'A'
  ) test_records_with_count
  order by cnt
) top_test_records
order by test, phase
;
```

Here is the same with RANK OVER instead of TOP WITH TIES:

```
select
  test, phase
from
(
  select
    test, phase, rank() over (order by cnt) as rnk
  from
  (
    select test, phase, count(*) over (partition by test) as cnt
    from table
    where file = 'A'
  ) test_records_with_count
) test_records_ranked
where rnk = 1
order by test, phase
;
```

This second approach could be easily adjusted so as to get the results for more than one file.

There are other ways to approach this problem. You could do without analytic functions at all for instance, which would involve reading the table more than once.

Comment: Your work is core solution for my problem .. I added distinct keyword to find the test no only. And with your query , I can add field name to the query without changing the result.. Thanks:)